# Migrating data from Jira Cloud to Existing Jira Server

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am planning to migrate data from Jira cloud to Jira server (data center addition).

I have found couple of docs from atlassian but it didn't lay down progress to migrate to existing Jira server.

Have anyone came across this scenario and if yes, what procedure did you follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a zip with the database content plus attachments. With that you can recreate your instance in JIRA SERVER. There is an option in the Admin section for that (or you can request it to Atlassian Support).